# Editing any users' post - possible security issue?

Tags: discussion, support

Some time ago I've found that I am able to edit any users' question, answer or comment on StackOverflow (but along with this I can not even leave a comment to anybody's answer because of lack of a reputation!). Can anyone else confirm this behavior? I believe that this is some kind of a bug, isn't it?

Comment: Only moderators can edit another user's comments...

Comment: You can't edit a comment, only questions and answers.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can **suggest** edits on any post (but no comments). If you do not have [enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) then these edits first go into the review queue and will be reviewed before they are accepted.

So all is fine.

Comment: And of course, any edit can be rolled back. Abuse your privileges and you will get caught.

Comment: Thanks for reply, apparently you're right. I've even tried to edit your answer to check it ))   I've been just misleaded by interface: firstly, link for suggest editing is called "edit", like when editing my own message, and secondly there's nothing during editing another's user post saying that changes will not be immediately visible to everyone without review.